# How to echo an stdClass Object Array's array values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array within an STDClass object as my select options. I cannot understand how to echo its values.

```
var $fields = array( array(
   'name'   => 'icon',
   'type'   => 'select',
   'items' => array(0 => 'news', 1 => 'technology', 2 => 'products'),
    ),  
);
```

Then within the widget function:

```
function widget($args, $instance)
{
$inst = (object) wp_parse_args($instance, array(
        'icon'              => '',
        'title'             => '',
        'display_title'     => '',
        'content'           => '',
        'link_text'         => '',
    ));
}
```

Within this function 
`echo $inst->icon;` gives me the key. How do I get the value?

Comment: What does `wp_parse_args` do?

Comment: @Popnoodles http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args

Comment: @BenRacicot you mean `$inst->icon` returns "icon" ?

Comment: Hey everyone, @Adelphia no, it returns the key of the chosen icon. If I choose the first icon it returns 0.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wordpress but have you tried just `'items' => array('news','technology','products')`

Comment: @Adelphia turns out its supposed to echo the keys when using an array with a select option. Using the keys as labels. Thanks for your help guiding me there.

Comment: can you var_dump(inst) and write result here, we can provide you better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'old' array notation instead of the arrow?

`echo $inst['icon']`;

*Source* : that is how they seem to print values in this documentation : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args